# Oracle - Data with one id in one line

Tags: sql, oracle

New to sql, trying to create a query for **reporting**.

The following table is available:

| Number | NO | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 332 | 14.11.22 |
| 111 | 331 | 13.11.22 |
| 111 | 330 | 13.11.22 |
| 122 | 312 | 12.11.22 |
| 122 | 311 | 11.11.22 |
| 122 | 310 | 11.11.22 |

I would like to come to this view - A row in one row had a number, a maximum and a minimum NO and the corresponding dates and quantities associated with it:

| Number | NO min | Date min | NO max | Date max | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 330 | 13.11.22 | 332 | 14.11.22 | 3 |
| 122 | 310 | 11.11.22 | 312 | 12.11.22 | 3 |

Comment: Use MAX and MIN on both NO and date to generate the columns 2 to 5, use COUNT to generate the column6 and apply a GROUP BY number clause in your query. I think it would be much better when you create the entire query or at least show what you have tried than just copy an answer from here.

Comment: Thank you for your help, everything worked out. @JonasMetzler

Comment: You're welcome and good work to do this on your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  with t(Num,   Start_number, Date_start) as (
select 111 , 225 , '11.11.22' from dual union all
select 111 , 223 , '9.11.22' from dual union all
select 111 , 220 , '9.11.22' from dual union all
select 222 , 347 , '11.11.22' from dual union all
select 222 , 345 , '11.11.22' from dual union all
select 222 , 343 , '10.11.22' from dual
)
select 
  Num,
  min(Start_number) as minStart,
  max(Start_number) as maxStart,
  min(Date_start) as minDate,
  max(Date_start) as maxDate,
  Count(Start_number) as cnt
from t
group by Num
order by minDate
```